# What is the longest file path that Windows can handle?

Tags: windows, path

What is the longest file path that Windows can handle?

Comment: A similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista. To be honest, I still don't understand whether the maximum length of an individual  filename is 255 or 256 characters. (Even after the discussion with @phuclv below.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[Maximum Path Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maximum_path_length) (from MSDN)

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is **MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters**. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\<some 256 character path string><NUL>" where "<NUL>" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

Comment: You should mention that you can handle paths that exceed this limit by prefixing it with `\\?\` (I think it was that character sequence).

Comment: you should also state the limit for unicode-paths mentioned in the 2nd paragraph: ~32k

Comment: 260? 256 characters ignoring drive:\ and terminator. It's 2009, why do we only get a byte of characters to play around with?

Comment: @Phoshi The APIs to use longer paths aren't used by the OS by default, because passing in arbitarily long strings to applications that were poorly written by developers who knew the path could never be longer than 260 chars and decided to allocate a fixed length array to hold it would result in a huge number of buffer overflows leading to applications crashing and/or being exploited.  Slightly better implementations by devs with the same mis-knowledge would abort because their path validation reported a too long error.

Answer (score 14):

XP file path - 250 characters

Vista file path - 260 characters

The longest path on a clean install of Windows XP is 152 characters.

The longest path on a semi-clean install of Windows Vista is 195 characters

Windows XP allows file names upto 255 characters in length

Windows Vista allows even longer filenames containing upto 260 characters.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000729.html

Comment: this is just true if you dont use the unicode-api, which extends the limit a bit (~32k, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maximum%5Fpath%5Flength)

Comment: hmmm.  at that rate, the limit in Win7 ought to be around 265 characters, no?

Comment: Why would they increase the limit by ten characters? Doesn't seem worth it, does it :\

Comment: this is **absolutely incorrect**. The maximum filename length is still 255 characters in any Windows, since that's the NTFS limit. And `MAX_PATH` has always been 260 characters

Comment: @Phoshi it's because MS didn't make that change. The limit is the same. This answer is just nonsense

Answer (score 10):

The *"classic"* limit is ***260*** characters: `drive letter` + `:\` + `255 characters of filename` + `\` (or for rounding) + `null terminator` as said in the other answers

However the real internal limit is **32767** characters which can be achieved by prepending `\\?\` to get a [fully qualified path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths)

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the `lpMaximumComponentLength` parameter of the `GetVolumeInformation` function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an extended-length path, use the `"\\?\"` prefix. For example, `"\\?\D:\very long path"`.

If due to some reasons the fully-qualified paths cannot be used then deeper directories can be accessed by mounting to a drive letter with [`subst`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491006(v=technet.10))/[`diskpart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive) or by creating a [junction](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)/[symlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) to shorten the path

Since Windows 10 version 1607 the `MAX_PATH` limit has also been removed although not by default

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, `MAX_PATH` limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file

Note that [Joe's answer is completely wrong](https://superuser.com/a/14892/241386). Max (long) file name length has always been 255 characters and `MAX_PATH` has always been 260

Comment: The best answer here. The most accurate and easiest to understand. +1

Comment: However, it is not clear to me what does the \ after the `255 characters of filename` mean. As I know, a typical path looks like c:\foo\bar (or c:\foo\bar\a.txt), not c:\foo\bar\ (or c:\foo\bar\a.txt\\). There is no trailing backslash. Could you explain what you mean by it?

Comment: (There were some errors in my previous comment. Now all of them are fixed.)

Comment: @johnc.j. as I said, it can be a path to a folder with trailing slash, or simply for making the size an even number which is better for alignment

Comment: Prepend \\?\, don't append \\?\

Answer (score 8):

Windows constant `MAX_PATH` is equal to 260 as other answers says, however, the real longest path is 32767.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).

32k is while using UNICODE, but now we must use it, so we should also use such max path length.

Also, you can take a look into [my answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452546/1237747) which explains some things more detailed about maximum path length.