# Is it possible to change the maximum folder+file length? (on win 7)

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extend maximum file path size in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/37737/extend-maximum-file-path-size-in-windows-7)

Hi all,

I wish to allow my computer (on windows 7) to work with longer folder+file names.

Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of this question?

http://superuser.com/questions/37737/extend-maximum-file-path-size-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Not without recompiling the operating system, or at least parts of it. Plus, you can't guarantee that applications will take the size change well.