# How to widen properties windows/dialogs in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, properties

I need to widen some properties windows/dialogs in Windows 7 to be able to read some very long paths.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

PS: I have already tried ResizeEnable and AuthoHotKeys, and let's just say that I do not want to use them again, ever.  Please do not recommend them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extend the maximum file path size in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/37737/how-do-i-extend-the-maximum-file-path-size-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Diogo I'm not sure that' s a duplicate. I think this user wants to stretch visible dialog Window to reveal hidden text. The flagged dupe seems to be about the number of characters available in a Windows file path.

Comment: Cannot you drag window side by mouse to view full path?

Comment: If it's a long path, try highlighting it with the cursor and moving your cursor to the right, like you're selecting text. That's worked for me on occasion.

Comment: @Asif: no (try it, you'll see)

Comment: @ekaj: I'd be happy to accept your comment if you post it as an answer.  (Granted, your comment does not answer the question as I asked it, strictly speaking, but it gets "to the heart of the matter".)

Comment: Only accept it if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a long path, try highlighting it with the cursor and moving your cursor to the right, like you're selecting text. That's worked for me on occasion.