# Ways to improve completeness of files for data recovery and scanning?

Tags: data-recovery

I am using R-studio for data recovery on one of my ntfs partition. There is a pdf file about 16MB, but the software can only recover 15MB of it. So I am thinking about what ways can be used to improve the quality of scanning and recovery by the software?

I am looking around its preferences. I am not quite sure whether there are some adjustable parameters for scanning and recovery which can be fine-tuned to improve the quality?

R-studio has a free demo version, for which scanning is free,but recovery isn't. 
It is downloadable from http://www.data-recovery-software.net/Data_Recovery_Download.shtml
Its manual is here http://www.r-tt.com/downloads/Recovery_Manual.pdf. I have tried my best to search for answers in the manual, but failed to find one. Their technical support is not as good as their software, and helpless usually in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you had absolutely no writes to the device in question after files were deleted, there is always a chance that one or more files may be partially or fully unrecoverable.

If you are running Windows from this drive, given that it writes various things to disk (registry updates, logs) the more time that passes, the more chances that a deleted file may be overwritten and become unrecoverable.  First rule of recovery is to remove the device in question and use an operating system running from a separate disk (or recovery CD/flash drive) to examine and perform recovery operations.

You could try other recovery tools, such as Piriform's Recuva, but it's likely the portion of the file that could not be recovered was overwritten by a later file written to disk.

Take this opportunity to develop a better backup plan to avoid needing to perform the recovery in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Does changing the partition to be read-only to all users (system, administrators, ...) protect it from being written?

Comment: Another possibility to my question: does data recovery software scan in some storage unit, like 64 KB, 16KB, ...? So if decreasing the scan storage unit to 1 byte, will  that improve the quality of scanning and recovery? Note: I am just guessing, and not sure if software for data recovery works in that way.

Comment: I tried Recuva before, but my paths are too long to be handled by it under Windows. R-studio has a Linux version, which may be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I actually used all 3 tools mentioned in my answer to your previous query. I did end up with a whole bunch of partial files (sadly unavoidable), and since I was paranoid about the completeness of any given recovered file, I ended up with multiple copies of each recovered by the different programs. Of course, some files were found by one program and not the other, but in general I spent more than two weeks sorting through the debris, comparing copies, keeping (mostly) the biggest ones out of the multiple versions and so on. For some files that were recovered partially, I was able to track down the source and download the remaining portions after a hash check or similar. All in all, I was able to recover roughly 80-85%, not of the total, but of the files I *really* wanted. I feel that was a *very* decent success rate, given the drive in my case was physically failing (I even used the freezer trick in the end!) In another instance when I did this for a friend who had accidentally formatted the wrong drive and then used the system for a few hours, I was able to recover around 90% of his files.

The process *is* going to take time and effort and if you can, you absolutely should try out more than one program, since they all don't work the exact same way and their recovery algorithms differ. Talking specifically about R-Studio, while it has been a while I do remember that I turned on the search for Known File Types, even though it added hours to the scan time. In this mode the program utilises knowledge of the internal format/structure of common file types to identify and recover as much of the file content as possible. I did manage to shave off a lot of the scan time though by going to the File Types dialog box (manual - pg. 32) and unchecking all those types that I knew I never had on my drive. This saved the program from wasting time searching for non-existent file types. I also made sure I saved the scan information, so that in subsequent runs I could simply load it and save hours on re-scanning. The other settings I tweaked were related to skipping bad blocks/unreadable areas of the drive, which I don't think is a problem in your case since your drive's otherwise fine.

Can't think of anything else I did for R-Studio specifically. I also went through all the settings for the other two programs and basically enabled any option that seemed to me like it would improve the scan quality, irrespective of the time it would take. Didn't bother with tech support, I know what they're like. In any case, once the programs were done it was all manual work to sift through and salvage what I could from the results returned.

Comment: Thanks, Karan! (1) WHat are some good applications that can help sorting through the debirs, comparing copies, etc? Under Linux (preferably) or Windows? (2) What do you think about the strengths and weaknesses of the 3 tools? In my case, most files were created under Ubuntu with too deep paths to be handled by Windows and software under it, so I ended up purchasing R Studio for Linux, although data loss happened under Windows. The other two tools seem to work under Windows only, and  likely not able to handle long paths. (3) Are there some good books or references for data recovery algorithms?

Comment: If you're retrieving full paths and it exceeds Windows' MAXPATH, yes, you will face problems under Windows. As for the strengths and weaknesses, I have no means of knowing/comparing the actual algos used of course, but I did find that ZAR did a slightly better job recovering my RAR/ZIP/7z archives, whereas with the other two many were corrupted. As for other apps, I used some binary compare programs (see question 125376 for some Linux examples), hex editors and just plain manual viewing. As far as algos go, I am sure there are books/technical papers, but what do you intend to do with the info?

Comment: Just to learn about the basics of data recovery, not actually dreaming of writing a tool my own. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is due to [**fragmentation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29). When a file is written to disk, it is not always stored with all of its contents in a row. Whenever you delete a file, it frees up some blocks on disk, but there may be another file right after it. This leaves a chunk of free space that is as big as the deleted file (rounded up to the nearest cluster size). If you then write a file that is bigger than the deleted file, it may get written to that block, but only as much as fits, with the rest being written to the next available free block. This file is now fragmented.

Most people think of disk fragmentation as being bad for performance, but the truth is, it is *far* more problematic and troublesome for data-recovery. When you lose a file and need to recover it, if the file is not fragmented, then all you need to do is to find the beginning of the file and know its size. Then you can simply copy the appropriate number of clusters. This is made easier when using [file signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#File_header) which are usually stored in the header (i.e., at he start of the file). Therefore, all you have to do is to scan the disk, looking for patterns that indicate the beginning of a file, and then copy a certain number of blocks to recover the file (usually resulting in some extraneous junk at the end of the file; but that’s better than nothing).

If the file is fragmented however, it becomes much more difficult to recover the file because without the file-system information telling you where each chunk of the file is stored, there is no way to know which clusters belong to which files. You may be able to find a file and get a part of it, for example the first 15MB that happen to be stored in a row, but then that last 1MB may be stored somewhere else and there’s no way to know that.

If you are trying to recover a text-file, you may be able to manually locate the separate pieces scattered around the disk and stitch them back together, but even that is difficult if you happened to be editing the file and saved several times, making changes each time. How do you know if the next piece is from the latest version of the file or from an earlier piece? It *is* possible, but quite time-consuming. Most binary files on the other hand are flat out impossible to recover if they are fragmented (I suppose you *could* find pieces of certain types of binary files like MP3s in which even fragments can be “viewed”).

Keeping your disk defragmented makes data-recovery much easier. Unfortunately, due to the limited write-capability of SSD drives, many people are actually defragmenting *less*, which puts data at more risk of being permanently lost.

---

Let’s say that your files are stored on disk as shown below. The purple clusters are where your file is stored. The first 15MB of the file are stored in a row, but the last 1MB is stored separately, earlier on the disk. The yellow line shows the beginning of the file where the PDF signature was found. The program found the signature and identified a PDF file, but was only able to copy the first 15MB before finding another file. It has no way to know where the last 1MB is located because the cluster chain is, or rather *was* stored in the file-system.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Most of my files on that ntfs partition were created under Ubuntu. If I remember correctly, defragmentation isn't necessary under Linux, isn't it?

Comment: @SteveO, defragmentation is not an OS-specific thing; *any* OS that can create and delete files *will* eventually end up with fragmented files. It is not file-system–specific either. Basically there is *no way* to prevent fragmentation short of constantly defragmenting everything. (Plus, I have never heard of Linux being immune to fragmentation; which makes sense.)