# What practical workarounds exist for dealing with 'too long' file paths?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, path

My workplace has a network drive anyone can access.  Because of this, there exist file paths which are so long that if you try to create a reasonably named file within them, the file path will exceed the maximum allowable length.

In some cases, I have authority to reduce the path length by removing redundancies, etc.  In other cases, it's part of a long standing project and I am forced to use that path.

How do I work with a shared network file path which is too long to allow files with practical names?

Edit: Please note, that if I could delete/revise the file path, I would.  The operating system is capable of updating the path.  The question, however, is that I am not authorized to update it.  That is, a senior colleague/manager says, "Do not change this file path."  What options are there for working within this constraint?

Looking around, these are the suggestions I have found:

1. Create a new folder somewhere else on the shared drive which has a shorter path.  Include a shortcut to the new folder at the end of the too long path.  A shortcut could be placed in the new folder which points to the too long folder.
2. Change the hearts and minds of my colleagues.

Are there any others?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/14883/what-is-the-longest-file-path-that-windows-can-handle?rq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/45697/how-to-delete-a-file-in-windows-with-a-too-long-filename?rq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/718223/force-delete-files-with-a-rather-large-name?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep-and-avoid-file-name-too-lon?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Those are all the workarounds for "Dealing with" long paths, but working with them as in managing and *keeping* them would be highly dependant on how your organisation works. It would generally be best to move away from network filesystems as your sole storage methods unless you have backups. Version control systems generally offer better handling of files and more data security.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to provide those links.  They, unfortunately, do not address the question.  I have tried to clarify the question in the original post.  Namely, it is not how to delete a file path or what systems would better handle file management, but rather, what is an effective way to work within restraint of a mandated file path?

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, then it is subject to opinion and too broad. SuperUser is best at answering specific questions with specific answers. Your question is a good question, but it will really receive much better answers in a forum where open discussion is the strength.

Comment: with Win10 v1607, Microsoft started working on it: http://superuser.com/a/1114683/174557, but Explorer is not ready to use long paths.

Comment: a shortcut won't work for such cases. You have to mount the folder or create a junction/symlink if you can't use fully qualified paths. If you can't update to Windows 10 and don't like those solutions then there's no other way